# how to check if one `string` tensor is alphabetically greater than another `string` tensor in tensorflow >= 2.0.0?

Tags: string, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I know how to check equality of two `string` tensors. Any of those works just fine.

`tf.constant('foo') == 'foo'` or

`tf.math.equal(tf.constant('foo'), 'foo')` or

`tf.equal(tf.constant('foo'), 'foo')`

However, I couldn't find a way to check if one `string` tensor alphabetically greater/lower than another one.

Neither of those works and produces the same error:

`tf.constant('foo') > 'foo'` or

`tf.math.greater(tf.constant('foo'), 'foo')` or

`tf.greater(tf.constant('foo'), 'foo')`

**error message:**

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of string is not in the list of allowed values: float, double, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, half, uint32, uint64
; NodeDef: {{node Greater}}; Op<name=Greater; signature=x:T, y:T -> z:bool; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, DT_INT8, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_UINT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]> [Op:Greater]

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my own answer. I encourage other folks to chime in with their solutions.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def maybe_cast_to_tensor(maybe_tensor):
    if not isinstance(maybe_tensor, tf.Tensor):
        return tf.constant(maybe_tensor)
    return maybe_tensor

def is_lower(op1, op2):
    op1 = maybe_cast_to_tensor(op1)
    op2 = maybe_cast_to_tensor(op2)

    # cast strings to ints. we assume that `decode_raw` preserves order.
    op1 = tf.io.decode_raw(op1, tf.uint8)
    op2 = tf.io.decode_raw(op2, tf.uint8)

    max_len = tf.math.reduce_max([tf.shape(op1), tf.shape(op2)])

    # pad `op1`, `op2` to same size
    op1 = tf.pad(op1, [[0, max_len - tf.shape(op1)[0]]])
    op2 = tf.pad(op2, [[0, max_len - tf.shape(op2)[0]]])

    # the main logic
    # vectorized version that checks the existence of such `0 <= k` that:
    # 1. op1[i] == op2[i] for some prefix 1..(k-1)
    # 2. op1[k] < op2[k]
    prev_equal_mask = tf.math.cumsum(tf.cast(op1 == op2, tf.int32)) == tf.range(tf.shape(op1)[0]) + 1
    prev_equal_mask = tf.concat([tf.constant(True, shape=(1,)), prev_equal_mask[:-1]], 0)
    return tf.reduce_any(prev_equal_mask & (op1 < op2))

print(is_lower('ab', 'cd')) # true
print(is_lower('cd', 'ab')) # false
print(is_lower('ab', 'ab')) # false
print(is_lower('ab', 'abc')) # true
print(is_lower('abcd', 'abe')) # true
print(is_lower('abcd', 'abb')) # false
```